# Javascript Prompt Cancel Button not "Canceling"

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I've noticed that when you have a user enter text through a `prompt` window, the prompt will return `null` and continue moving on with the code. I want the cancel button to do what it says it does and cancel. I've tried several `if` statements, including:

```
var x= prompt("Please enter a number for <X>: (<X> + <Y>)");
if (x === null) {
    return;
}
var y= prompt("Please enter a number for <Y>: (<X> + <Y>)");
if (x === null) {
        return;
}   
eval ("x=x; y=y; alert(+x + + y)");
};
```

The above does not change anything

```
var x= prompt("Please enter a number for <X>: (<X> + <Y>)");
    if (verifyInput(false)) {
        return;
    }
var y= prompt("Please enter a number for <Y>: (<X> + <Y>)");
    if (verifyInput(false)) {
        return;
    }
eval ("x=x; y=y; alert(+x + + y)");
};
```

And this one makes both the OK and Cancel buttons return false, and the code does not continue even when OK is pressed.

Is their some code that will affect the Cancel button so that it stops the script from continuing? Thanks!

I am very new to this website so pardon me if I didn't make myself terribly clear :)

Comment: What's the deal with the `eval` statement? And what is `verifyInput`?

Comment: This is basically for a calculator function (which is why I accidentally left the `};` at the end. The `eval` "evaluates" the two prompt answers and alerts the result. I don't know what the `verifyInput` is, I just tried it from another question about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking equality to `null` when `prompt` returns a string; this won't work. Instead, this should be your condition:

```
if ( x === "" ) { / ... / }
```

Here you're checking for an empty string. Moreover, that eval statement doesn't do anything, you can execute the same code without it:

```
alert( +x + +y );
```

Comment: Thanks! The `if (x === "")` does the job perfectly!

Comment: This is the only answer I can +1 because it keeps the strict equals operator `===`. Though there is another way of doing this I'd accept; `if (!(x = prompt('blah'))) return;`

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is that you are using the identity operator (===) to check for null... null in of itself is an object, whereas your prompt results will be a string... therefore, it will never be true... use the equality operator instead (==).

You may also want to remove the eval statement, and instead just alert the results:

alert("" + (x + y));

Edit: Sorry just noticed that you'd like to perform an actual mathematical process here... here's code that works for me... real basic HTML page but should help you do what you need to:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="Prompter();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Prompter()
      {
      var x = prompt("Please enter a number for <X>: (<X> + <Y>)");
      var y = prompt("Please enter a number for <Y>: (<X> + <Y>)");
      if(x && y)
          alert("" + (parseInt(x) + parseInt(y)));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the command `break;`